# RSPEC not rendering JSON.jbuilder file (missing template error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec, controller, jbuilder

I am testing my rails application using RSpec, and am testing the controller. Specifically, I am trying to render my `jobs.json.jbuilder` view file.

**My Controller**

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_member!
  before_action :set_customer


def jobs
    @jobs = @customer.jobs
end
```

My corresponding view is located in :
`views/customers/jobs.json.jbuilder`

**My RSpec Test is:**

```
describe "GET job" do 
    it "renders the jobs view" do 
    get 'jobs', {id: @customer.id}, {format: :json}
    expect(response).to render_template("customers/jobs.json.jbuilder")
    end
end
```

**However the error I keep getting is:**

```
     Failure/Error: get :jobs, {id: @customer.id}, {format: :json}
     ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing template customers/jobs, application/jobs with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :slim]}. Searched in:
         * "#<RSpec::Rails::ViewRendering::EmptyTemplatePathSetDecorator:0x007fa219178f78>"
     # ./spec/support/engine_controller.rb:25:in `process_action'
     # ./spec/support/engine_controller.rb:3:in `get'
     # ./spec/controllers/customers_controller_spec.rb:31:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

NOTE: If I make a `jobs.html.erb` file.. then this error goes away, (and it renders the `jobs.html.erb` file ) - so my question is how do i render the `.json.jbuilder` view ?

Here is my `spec/support/engine_controller` file:

```
 module EngineController
   def get(action, parameters = nil, session = nil, flash = nil)
           process_action(action, parameters, session, flash, "GET")
   end 

    private
       def process_action(action, parameters = nil, session = nil, flash =       nil, method = "GET")
        parameters ||= {}
        process(action, method, parameters.merge!(:use_route => :my_engine_name), session, flash, )
      end
```

Answer (score 4):

Fixed the problem by using this syntax:

```
describe "GET job" do 
  it 'renders the jobs view' do 
    get 'jobs', { id: @customer.id, format: :json }
    expect(response).to render_template("customers/jobs")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a very late answer, but, for those who are still coming to this question...

For rendering `json.jbuilder` by default you should put it on routes.rb

in this case...

```rb
resources :costumers, defaults: { format: :json }, only: [...] do
  get 'job', to: 'costumers#job'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

worth noting that adding

```
config.render_views = true
```

to the RSpec.configure in the rails_helper is also needed

as per [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58741194/rails-json-jbuilder-api-with-rspec-actionviewmissingtemplate)